# Comparing individual words in arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, split

I am looking for a way to take user input for two sentences and then have the user pick a number that would have the program check to see if the word that corresponds to that number is the same in both sentences.

So if there were 8 words in each sentence and they chose number 4, the program would compare the fourth word on both sentences and then tell the user that the two "Strings" match.

Would it be better to use array's or just strings?

Would I use split in this instance?

Comment: That is too complicated to be done in a small piece of code. You would need Natural Language Processing and Artificial Intelligence to detect a word boundary. If a user inputs a string `"New York city"`, should it be one word, or two words `New York` and `city`, or three? Unless you can detect the word boundaries, you cannot count the words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think split is a good option.

Assuming word boundaries are whitespace, you could do something like this:

```
string1 = "my name is Jerry"
string2 = "his name was Pete"

number = 2
string1.split(/\s/)[number - 1] == string2.split(/\s/)[number - 1]
#=> true

number = 3
string1.split(/\s/)[number - 1] == string2.split(/\s/)[number - 1]
#=> false
```

Comment: I know that an array counts from 0,1,2,... but does a string start with 1?

Comment: @user3295198 String#split yields an Array as well. Point is he wants to compare the 2nd and 3rd words, so uses indices 1 and 2, respectively.

Comment: Thanks Levi, it looks like that works after adding my code for user input and doing an if then else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays would be best since they are easier to handle. Its more of a personal preference too.
I would do something like this

```
 sentence_1 = "The brown fox jumped over the white fence" || (User Input)
 sentence_2 = "The White fox ran over the white rails" || (User Input)

 array_1 = sentence_1.split(" ")
 array_2 = sentence_2.split(" ")

 number = gets.to_i

  # This is assuming user enters numbers starting from 1 and not 0

 number = number - 1  #index

 word_1 = array_1[number] rescue ''
 word_2 = array_2[number] rescue ''

 unless word_1 == '' || word_2 == ''
     word_1 == word_2 ? (puts "Match: #{word_1} = #{word_2}") : (puts "MisMatch :#{word_1} Not equal #{word_2}")
 else
     puts "The sentence is not that long"
 end
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks stacked for life, yours is also a good answer. Can there be two checked answers on here?

Comment: You can upvote each helpful answer, but you can only choose one answer to accept.

Comment: The `rescue` does nothing; if the number is too large you don't get an error, you get `nil`.

Comment: Yep custom rescue can be added here. It was just a prototype